# Using terraform how can I use one service account and define permissions on GCP services on another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am currently trying to use a service account that is already created in one project and use it again in a different project. We have cloud function running in a project B which needs to be invoked from a service account in project A. Is there a terraform resource we can use to define permissions cross project ? Thanks for your help.

Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: Why dont you one service account and use correct permissions and you dont have to manage per project SA for cross account role.

Comment: Your terraform service account must have the permission on the project B to grant an account to invoke the function. That account can be a user account, or a service account, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Are you referring to impersonating a service account in different project   https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#attaching-different-project

Comment: How do you perform impersonation? Usually, impersonation is simply a role (service account user) that you grant on a service account.